# How to make correct mouse transition between displays with different DPI?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have 2 displays side by side. They have almost the same physical size but different DPI (-> resolution).

Is there a way to make mouse pointer transition correctly between them? When pointer exits second display at the top windows thinks that it corresponds to about 3/4 of first display height when in reality it should be almost on top of first display.

This settings window only allows me to drag second display around but doesn't allow to resize it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Little Big Mouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/wiki). You have two ways to go:

- [Allow Corner Crossing](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/wiki#interface)

  > Enables virtual corner crossing. If your displays are not at equal heights, LBM can smooth corner mouse transitions. LBM calculates the direction your mouse pointer leaves the screen and LBM places it at the corresponding point on the next display.
- [Change Your Reported Display Sizes](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/wiki#change-your-reported-display-sizes) and set the same height values for the screens, then position them next to each other.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! What a perfect tool!

Comment: Little Big Mouse brilliant project. Works really great. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I've been using [cursr](https://cursr.app) lately, works great, minimal functionality (at least for now) to map cursor position between borders, but simple and easy to use

Comment: It appears that you have recommended this app multiple times.  Please disclose if you are simply a satisfied user or have an affiliation with this app.

Answer (score -2):

The relative sizes shown by Windows reflect the resolutions on each screen.

If you want the second screen larger, you need to set it to a larger resolution.

Comment: DPI means "Dots per inch". That means that while having the same physical size the screens have different number of dots on them. Different number of dots means different resolution.